# Implement SockJS-client with STOMP messaging protocol in REACT NATIVE

Tags: react-native, sockets, websocket, stompjs

For my webapplication I am using socketJs with STOMP messaging. I also want to use this is my react native project. Tried a couple of solutions but these didn`t work.

Can someone explain or help me with how to implement sockets with STOMP?

Thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

const socket = new SockJs(`${BASE_URL}/api/websocket?access_token=${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`);
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);